# What is this formatting mark symbol in MS Word called and how to remove it?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

[image]

What is this formatting mark symbol in MS Word called and how to remove it?

Comment: What formatting mark? Your image is full of them.

Comment: I second Appleoddity's question, but see if [this guide](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm) has an explanation on any of the symbols you're wondering about.

Comment: Dots are spaces, pilcrows mark the paragraphs (at the end of each line). Offhand, I would guess the grey boxes may not be a formatting symbols. Perhaps you can toggle the symbols settings in Word to see of they are affected.